# Best way to write JS async/await code and proceed conditionally

Tags: javascript, async-await

So I am writing a server backend using express, and I have the following code, where all database functions are asynchronous:

```
if(!!data.value) {
    database.exeuteSomeUpdate().catch(err => {return res.status(400).json({message: "Wrong inputs"})});
} else {
    database.createRow().catch(err => {return res.status(500).json({err})});
}

//proceed with other functions
```

I would like the entire function to end when database has encountered some error (the two return statements) but unfortunately they are in their own functions and a return in that function does not terminate the outer function.

I know this would be possible by using the .next() in promises but since there will be a lot of different queries and using .next with each will create a callback hell therefore I would like to avoid that, is there a quick way to write the function and have the catches terminate the function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This would be pretty easy if you used `await` instead of `.then`. Inside an `async` function, do:

```
if (data.value) {
  try {
    await database.exeuteSomeUpdate();
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(400).json({message: "Wrong inputs"});
  }
} else {
  try {
    await database.createRow();
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(500).json({err});
  }
}
//proceed with other functions
```

Also note that `if(!!data.value) {` simplifies to `if(data.value) {`.

If you need to use the resolve values, you could make a wrapper function to keep things DRY and `const`, but it looks a bit odd:

```
const handleProm = (prom, handleReject) => {
  return prom.catch((err) => {
    handleReject(err);
    throw err;
  });
};
```

```
try {
  const result1 = await handleProm(
    database.exeuteSomeUpdate(),
    err => res.status(400).json({message: "Wrong inputs"})
  );
  // put all other awaits inside this try
} catch (e) {
  // do nothing; handleReject already handled it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But if I were to get the values of the awaits (i.e.) try {
const k = await database.executeSomeUpdate(); } catch (e) { //error}
k.val then I would have to declare every const outside, so I was wondering if there is a better one-liner solution

Comment: I suppose you could make a wrapper function to which you pass the Promise and a catch function, which either returns the resolve